# <div> within another of the same size and position:absolute;

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have a question about the position attribute, looks the `<div class='bloqued'></div>`, I need to get the same size as the parent div in any circumstance (including resizing the page), Is it possible? Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/vwuUj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the position of your parent container `relative`, like so:

```
.text {
  position: relative;
}
```

This sets the width and height limits for your absolutely-positioned `bloqued` div inside

[I updated your original script](http://jsfiddle.net/vwuUj/1/) to illustrate.

Comment: Is amazing, is fantastic, is crazy, is magical! Thanks man, worked perfectly. (: